# QGIS workflow for tagging images and producing maps based on tags

Tags: qgis, photos

Is there any robust workflow to produce a contour map based on tags associated with georeferenced pictures? Specifically, I collected 3000 georeferenced photos of a meadow. Before of shooting each photo, I placed a frame (i.e., quadrat) on the ground. This allows me to easily quantify the type and number of organisms comprised within the quadrat. For instance, photo 1.jpg contains 3 daisies, 1 orchid; photo 3000.jpg contains 2 daisies, 7 orchids. I would like to tag the photos (each tag represent a flower species) and then produce a set of contour maps showing the density of each flower.

I tried the nice software BPS (Benthic Photo Survey: http://jkibele.github.io/benthic_photo_survey/docs/), which helps in tagging the photo and exporting a Shapefile with data attributed points for each photo’s location.  Since the software has been discontinued since 2015, I am asking if are there any alternative solution for attributing values to photos and then importing those values into QGIS.

Comment: Your images are georeferenced but not tagged yet, right?

Comment: well does your camera have gps? there's this tool called "import geotagged pictures" in qgis processing, it's part of the installation, not a plugin